# I don’t undestand why my JS function results in an error

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript, and I don't understand why this JS function results in an error.

```
function fun(){
    console.log('foo');
    return {
      fun: function(){
        fun();
      }
    };
}

fun().fun(); // 'foo','foo'

fun().fun().fun(); // Error: Cannot read property 'fun' of undefined
```

**fun().**

Comment: The function in the returned object does not have a  `return` statement.

Comment: you are missing your return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time a function is called that does not return something the default return is always provided by the JavaScript runtime. The default return is `undefined`. Therefore, when you attempt to call 'fun()' the third time, an attempt is made to find an Object property called 'fun', but the previous call simply return `undefined` - hence: *Cannot read property 'fun' of undefined*

So try this instead:

```js
function fun(){
    console.log('foo');
    return {
      fun: function(){
        return fun();
      }
    };
}

fun().fun();

fun().fun().fun();
```

This returns the output of the function call - which is the intended Object.

Comment: Acceptable answer